# How to secure and restrict user access to an API hosted in AWS Beaskstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I am looking at hosting an API application in Beanstalk. I want to restrict access to everyone except for one person (tester) then when deploying it in production control who has access to it.

The API currently uses an API key and the user will need to authorize access but is there a way to restrict anyone finding the endpoint hitting the it. Do I need to look at restricting access via security groups? I will not know the IP address of the users.

I am potentially not looking at creating IAM access in AWS for this either.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS solution is to make the API in Elastic Beanstalk private, so it can only be accessed from the VPC, and then place [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) in front of it.

If you don't want to use AWS API Gateway, or some sort of [3rd party API Gateway](https://blog.cloudflare.com/api-gateway/), and you don't know what your user's IP addresses are, then there is no way for you to prevent anyone from sending requests to the API endpoint while having your API accessible from the Internet.

Another option would be to make the API private (VPC only), and use [AWS Client VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/client-vpn/), requiring your tester to establish a VPN connection before testing.